# What is the correct way to update / delete / insert a record into MySQL and Predis together in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3, predis

I am starting with Laravel Predis and Redis. The question is, what's the best way to handle a update in Laravel and Redis together? Is this the best way or can t be done simpler?

Eloquent update:

```
    $article = Article::find(1);
    $article->title         = Input::get('title');
    $article->save();
```

Redis Hmset:

```
    $client = Redis::connection();
    $client->hmset('testtest', ['1'=> 'testtest']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At laravel, creating a model is a must for you, this is a sample model for you:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    // set your table name from your database
    protected $table = 'articles';

    // set each field at table
    protected $fillable = [ 'title', 'content', 'status' ];
}
```

For Update:

```
$article = Article::find(1);
$article->update( [
    'title' => Input::get( 'title' ),
    'content' => Input::get( 'content' ),
    'status' => Input::get( 'status' ),
] );
```

For automatically update when there's an update :

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::updated( function( $article ) {
        $client = Redis::connection();
        $client->hmset('testtest', ['1'=> 'testtest']);
    });
}
```

Comment: yes i know and redis also. But is my way the simplest or is there a simplerer way?

Comment: if that so, your code is already right and best at laravel format

Comment: Hmmm, so there is no way to do an update Eloquent and Redis in 1 instance. Probably make my own class...

Comment: @Bas i updated my answer, there is a function that could trigger custom function when update a model

Comment: Tnx! Where can I put this feature?

Comment: at your Article Model